# A resource exists with a different case

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm unable to build my android app due to a strange error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The project was not built due
>   to "A resource exists with a different case:
>   '/ProjectName/bin/classes/com/Name/ProjectName'.". Fix the
>   problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may
>   be inconsistent   ProjectName     Unknown Java Problem

My file structure is the following: http://pastebin.com/6P6mEftD

I checked for files that had almost the same name and I couldn't find any. This was marked as the solution in a previously asked question that described the same error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same "resource exists with a different case" error.

The fix I had to make was in the AndroidManifest.xml file. My "package" parameter in the manifest XML tag did not exactly match the package name in my Java files. I suggest you look in the manifest XML and see if you spot the naming issue there.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this error and I studied a lot to solve it.

Here it goes:

All answers you might find, may be correct because there're differents causes for it.
To solve this issue, you must look into the "R.java" generated in the "gen" folder.

Once you opened it, look for two class that has the same name but is written with different cases. Example (mine): "String" ... "string"

Then, you will figure out that you miss spelt some thing. You never use Upcase letter to call strings at the xml file.

Example: android:contentDescription="@+String/imageView2"
DO NOT write string with capital S.

use:

android:contentDescription="@+string/imageView2" instead.

Once you locate the string you need to find where you put it with the find command.
Once you correct the "grammar", just clean your project.

Pease.

TMA.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the bin folder and "Clean project".

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
I follow Pauland and I deleted my bin folder. But nothing happened. Then I close the project and it openned with no errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Assure Package name has exactly same in Android Manifest and in the sources

Answer (score 0):

I copied project 'src' files from one project to another. In there I made a mistake in renaming the project folder as (com\company\projectName). The project folder name is expected to be all lower case. Then I deleted the bin & gen folders and rebuilt the project. All set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing all files under the ***target*** directory and letting the automatic rebuild execute.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my AndroidManifest.xml but somehow it was rolled back when I tried to rebuild.

Than I tried edit class name from gen folder using 'Refactor > Rename'.

I changed my class name from xxxxLib to xxxlib (lowercase).

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**1_** match "package" parameter in the manifest XML tag exactly with the package name in Src Java files.

com.example.myapp **is not** com.example.MyApp

**2_** delete all things in Gen folder

**3_** Project -> Clean

enjoy **:)**

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the incorrect package names defined in  `AndroidManifest.xml` file, remember the packages name are case-sensitive, then just a `Clean` > `Build Project`

update: sometimes is necessary a "hard reset" of the project deleting the folders `/gen` and `/bin`, then  `Build Project`